# Run some R code on server

Tags: r, rstudio, rstudio-server

Is it possible to execute some arbitrary R code from a machine on a server? I have some code that requires a lot of memory and can I select some R code and send it to be run on a server with more RAM (let's assume that the server is properly configured). I'll also add that I use RStudio Desktop IDE on Windows and have RStudio Server installed on a Ubuntu server.

Ideally, within RStudio, I should be able to select a few lines and execute those on the server and bring the results back to my desktop. (It is inefficient and error prone to copy the code to server, run, and copy the results back to desktop)

Does anything similar to this exist?

Comment: Good question, but setting this up may not be necessary.  You should be able to cut down the RAM usage on your computer.

Comment: If nothing else, you can always `scp` the R code over to the server, run it via `ssh`, dump the output to a file, and then `scp` the file back to your local machine.

Comment: hmm. thanks. I'll have to check this `scp`. I don't know what this is.

Comment: Take a look at `man scp`.